# Module TensorFlow has no attribute 'to_string'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to read a massive data set: *AAB,20170525,0.13,0.14,0.13,0.14,2060, etc.*

```
import tensorflow as tf

filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["D:/data/20170623.csv"])

reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=1)
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

record_defaults = [tf.constant([], dtype= tf.int32),
                   tf.constant([], dtype= tf.int32),
                   tf.constant([], dtype=tf.int32),
                   tf.constant([], dtype=tf.int32),
                   tf.constant([], dtype=tf.int32),
                   tf.constant([], dtype=tf.int32),
                   tf.constant([], dtype=tf.int32)]

col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7 = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults)
assert col1.dtype == tf.int32  
assert col2.dtype == tf.int32  
assert col3.dtype == tf.int32    
assert col4.dtype == tf.int32    
assert col5.dtype == tf.int32    
assert col6.dtype == tf.int32  
assert col7.dtype == tf.int32    

features = tf.stack([tf.to_string(col1), tf.to_string(col2)])

features = tf.stack([col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7])

with tf.Session() as sess:
  # Start populating the filename queue.
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

  for i in range(1200):
    # Retrieve a single instance:
    example, label = sess.run([features, col1])

  coord.request_stop()
  coord.join(threads)
```

> Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-18-8079bf3fc932>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/data/temp.py', wdir='D:/data')

  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/data/temp.py", line 33, in <module>
    features = tf.stack([tf.to_string(col1), tf.to_string(col2)])

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'to_string'
```

How do I return name based values from a csv file? containing dates, words, values, floats?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: do you want to write to a csv?

Comment: I'd like the program to remember a list of mixed data. I have a csv file with values and symbols, but I can't figure out how to get the program to recognize names and store the names from my csv file. Seems I'm stuck on figuring out how to store mixed data types and use the stored data to output logic. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you mean to use [`tf.as_string`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/as_string) rather than `to_string`?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot convert <function as_string at 0x0000022374B3B620> to a dtype. data type not understood

Comment: InvalidArgumentError: Field 0 in record 0 is not a valid int32: AAB.TO
  [[Node: DecodeCSV_19 = DecodeCSV[OUT_TYPE=[DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32], field_delim=",", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](ReaderReadV2_26:1, Const_98, Const_99, Const_100, Const_101, Const_102, Const_103, Const_104)]]

I tried your suggestion on the line of code features = tf.stack([tf.to_string(col1), tf.to_string(col2)])
The program still is having trouble intercepting the words and values. I'm sure ill eventually make it print each value.

Comment: I am still learning but if this isn't working you should try the default Python str() function and give it a try ?? Though it may be slower but it's worth a try.

Comment: by adding   input = tf.placeholder(tf.string)
and changing values from tf.int32 to tf.string i got it to show no errors and display this Tensor("DecodeCSV_28:0", shape=(), dtype=string)
Tensor("DecodeCSV_28:0", shape=(), dtype=string)
a few hundred times, still not showing the values, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the right `dtype` in the `tf.decode_csv` step by changing the `record_defaults` tensor so TensorFlow knows which `dtype` it should give to each column. This way you don't need to change it afterwards.

E.g. you could do something like that:

```
record_defaults = [[''],
                   [''],
                   [0.0],
                   [0.0],
                   [0.0],
                   tf.constant([], dtype=tf.int32),
                   tf.constant([], dtype=tf.int32)]
```

Comment: To everyone wanting to do what I tried to do, use pandas. Three minutes later I had a working printing of a data type:. import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#printscsv data for logic

df = pd.read_csv('yourfile', header=None)
df
print(df)

Comment: I thought the idea was to read CSV in TensorFlow, but if you just want to read a CSV then yes, Pandas is a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to import pandas.

If you're using anaconda.

```
conda install -c anaconda pandas=0.20.2
```

Wait till Pandas is installed, or search pandas under anaconda > tensorflow.

The code is:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("csvdirectoryhere")
print(df)
```

If you have multiple data sets you would like to import into python, you can change df to df1. print(df1) df1=pd.read_csv("csvdirectoryhere")df1 and so on.

To use the data being imported, you can do something [like this](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2015/03/16/Fast-Serialization), or follow the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

Special thanks to everyone who responded to my question.